# Custom vertex attributes in SceneKit

Tags: ios, macos, opengl-es, scenekit

I'm using SceneKit to generate some custom geometry. This is working fine, but I'm struggling to find a way to include custom vertex attributes. Specifically, I'm looking to include an additional SCNVector3 per vertex.

I've found plenty of examples which make use of shaderModifiers to include GLSL/Metal code that relies upon custom *uniform* values, but haven't come across a way of including vertex *attributes*. Is this possible with SceneKit, or is my thinking backwards?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

there doesn't seem to be a way to access custom geometry sources in shader modifiers. That said, if your data fits into a `float4` you can pass that data through `SCNGeometrySourceSemanticColor`.

The [Fox](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/Fox/Introduction/Intro.html) sample code uses the same technique to animate blades of grass. The displacement amount is baked into grayscale vertex colors as shown in the picture below.

[image: Data baked into the vertex colors]

Finally the following shader modifier reads the value of `_geometry.color` and makes sure to reset it to pure white so that the stored data doesn't affect the final color of the object.

```
 float offset = _geometry.color.x * (sin(1.2 * u_time + (_geometry.position.x+ _geometry.position.z)*4.0) + 0.5) * 0.02;
_geometry.position.x += offset;
_geometry.color.xyz = vec3(1.0);
```

Comment: So black means no possible displacement, white is maximum displacement.  Got it. But what does "if your data fits into a float3..." mean? Where/how/what is this limitation upon?

Comment: I updated my answer with `float4` instead of `float3`. `SCNGeometrySourceSemanticColor` is expected to hold color data. That's at most 4 floats for red, green, blue and alpha. You cannot use this technique to bake data that needs more information per vertex (such as a transform for instance).

Comment: Fascinating. I've long thought French people value transparency ;)

Comment: Thank you. I'll mark this as the accepted answer as it more directly provides an approach for my use-case. It's worth noting that I still consider @rickster's response to be incredibly helpful.

Answer (score 5):

To make custom geometry, you use [`SCNGeometrySource`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/scenekit/scngeometrysource) objects to provide the vertex position, normal, and texture coordinate attributes using a buffer or `Data` object full of values, then pass your geometry sources to the `SCNGeometry` [`init(sources:elements:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/scenekit/scngeometry/1522803-init) initializer.

When you create an `SCNGeometrySource`, you associate it with a "semantic" which is analogous to the GL/Metal vertex attribute. To create a custom vertex attribute, just give it a custom semantic. (In ObjC, `SCNGeometrySourceSemantic` is just a typedef for `NSString`, so you can provide your own string name. In Swift, `SCNGeometrySource.Semantic` is an enum-like struct that you can extend create new members with `String` raw values.)

To use your custom vertex attribute in a custom shader program, use [`setSemantic(_:forSymbol:options:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/scenekit/scnprogram/1522730-setsemantic) for GL shaders and (I think) [`handleBinding(ofBufferNamed:frequency:handler:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/scenekit/scnprogram/1524047-handlebinding) for Metal shaders.

Comment: The part of this about creating attributes is definitely there, but I'm not 100% sure on the shader (or shader modifier) hookups for custom attributes. @toyos probably knows about those...

Comment: Is this similar (in concept) to how a CGPath creates a SKShapeNode & CAShapeLayer, in the sense that once created any changes to the geometry can only be made by replacing the geometry ie no access to vertex position?

Comment: @Confused : yeah, sort of. Geometry sources (vertex buffers in GL/Metal speak) are designed to be sent over to GPU memory once (when you put a node with the geometry into your scene) so that you don't get a performance cost of sending them every frame. In SceneKit you can read the contents of a geometry source after creating it, but not edit them. (There is a feature for modifying geometry on the GPU at render time [with a Metal compute shader](https://developer.apple.com/reference/scenekit/scngeometrysource/1522873-init), though.)

Comment: Is this like the first stage of this: https://developer.apple.com/reference/scenekit/scnshadable wherein geometry shaders are processed first?

Comment: I mean this, as the entry point: https://developer.apple.com/reference/scenekit/scnshadermodifierentrypoint/1524108-geometry

Comment: But I don't really know what I'm talking about, just hoping it's possible to specifically, deliberately warp and deform geometry at a vertex level.

Comment: Once geometry data is in the GPU, one of the first things the GPU does each frame is run a vertex shader, so yes, SceneKit's geometry entry point is sort of related to that. We're veering out of the context of this post, and comments aren't a great place for an extended Q&A on the basics of GPU programming and how something like SceneKit builds on them. Try something like learnopengl.com, and post a new question if it leaves you wanting to ask more?

Comment: When's your book on Scene Kit coming out? ;)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to write this! Am I correct to assume that there's no supported way of accessing custom attributes via shaderModifiers? My understanding is that by implementing a custom SCNProgram I would essentially be throwing away a large amount of the rendering code afforded by SceneKit's default shader set.